# Factoring a polynomial

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to factor a polynomial a^3 - 4a^2 + 6a - 2. If I apply

```
Factor[a^3 - 4a^2 + 6a - 2.]
```

in Mathematica, the result is:

```
(-0.456311 + 1. a) (4.38298 - 3.54369 a + 1. a^2)
```

Is there a way of understanding how these coefficients (-0.456311, 4.38298, - 3.54369) come about? For example, obtaining these coefficients  as radicals?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Solve[a^3 - 4 a^2 + 6 a - 2 == 0, a]
```

will give you the coefficients as radicals.

Notice I removed that `.` so that Mathematica treats everything as exact integers instead of approximate floating point numbers